# How to check if a certain version of MySQL is installed using PowerShell?

Tags: mysql, powershell

I want to check if a PC already has a certain version of MySQL installed on it using PowerShell.

If it's not yet installed, I want to execute a `.msi` file to begin the installation.

Currently, I have this code:

```
$desiredGoVersion = "go1.20.4"
$desiredMySQLVersion = "8.0.32.0"

function Install-Go {
    Write-Host "Different version of Go is installed. Installing Go $desiredGoVersion."
    $installerFileName = $desiredGoVersion, ".windows-amd64.msi" -Join ""
    $desiredGoInstallerPath = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath "installers" | Join-Path -ChildPath $installerFileName

    # Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList $desiredGoInstallerPath
    Start-Process -FilePath $desiredGoInstallerPath -Wait
    Write-Host "Go installation completed."
    Check-Is-Go-Installed
}

function Check-Is-Go-Installed {
    # Check if the desired Go version is installed
    $goPath = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("GOPATH", "User")
    if (-not $goPath) {
        $goPath = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("GOPATH", "Machine")
    }

    if ($goPath) {
        $goExePath = Join-Path $goPath "bin\go.exe"
        
        if ($goExePath) {
            # Get the installed Go version
            $installedVersion = & $goExePath version | Select-String -Pattern "go version (.+?) "
            
            if ($installedVersion) {
                $installedVersion = $installedVersion.Matches.Groups[1].Value
                if ($installedVersion -eq $desiredGoVersion) {
                    Write-Host "Go version $desiredGoVersion is already installed."
                } else {
                    Install-Go
                }
            } else {
                Write-Host "Unable to determine installed Go version."
            }
        }
    } else {
        Install-Go
    }
}

function Install-MySQL{
    # Define the path to the downloaded MySQL installer
    $installerFileName = "mysql-installer-community-", $desiredMySQLVersion, ".msi" -Join ""
    $desiredMySQLInstallerPath = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath "installers" | Join-Path -ChildPath $installerFileName
    Write-Host $desiredMySQLInstallerPath

    if (Test-Path $desiredMySQLInstallerPath) {
        # Run the installer with the response file for silent installation
        Start-Process -FilePath $desiredMySQLInstallerPath -Wait

        Write-Host "MySQL version $mysqlVersion has been installed."
        Check-Is-MySQL-Installed
    } else {
        Write-Host "Installer not found at specified path."
    }
}

function Check-Is-MySQL-Installed {
    # Check if the desired Go version is installed
    $mysqlRegistryPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server $mysqlVersion"

    if (Test-Path $mysqlRegistryPath) {
        Write-Host "MySQL version $mysqlVersion is already installed."
    }else{
        Write-Host "MySQL version $mysqlVersion is not installed. Initiating installation..."

        Install-MySQL
    }
}

# Check-Is-Go-Installed
Check-Is-MySQL-Installed
```

The Go checking and installing are working as I expected, but I currently can't find a straight-forward way to check for the MySQL version that I want. Because for Go, we got GOPATH, but for MySQL, there's no environment variable to find where MySQL could be installed.

Comment: you can use `mysql --version` command and then parse its output

Comment: Hmm, I see. Will try that out

Comment: You could use `Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 8*' 'Version'` to read the version from the registry, but this will return multiple values if there are multiple version of MySQL 8 installed.

Comment: Will try that out as well. Thanks for the info

Comment: Hey @user1191247, thanks for the info, it pointed me to the right direction. But I have a small question, so the version I got is 8.0.32 but, for some reason, the installer's version is 8.0.32.0, with an extra .0 at the end. Do you know the reason for that?

Comment: I am sorry, but I have no idea. What's the reason for deploying MySQL like this? Is it mass installation on end user machines within a local network? If that is the case, an in process engine like SQLite _may_ be a better option. Obviously, we know nothing about your app, so just food for thought.

Comment: It's for "easy" installation for end users on the PC they'd like to use as our application's server. To be honest, I'd rather do it the old fashioned way (manually install MySQL, go, etc.) but my manager said that it should be something the end users (non-technical people) should be able to do. So, here I am. Also, I'm already done coding the server, so I'd rather not rewrite stuff

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that worked for me:

```
function Check-MySQL-Install {
    $registryPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE"
    $propertyName = "Version"
    $foundVersion = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $registryPath -Name $propertyName

    if ($foundVersion -eq $desiredMySQLVersion) {
        Write-Host "MySQL version $desiredMySQLVersion is already installed."
    } else {
        Install-MySQL
    }
}
```

I didn't find `MySQL Server 8` on my PC's registry, so I used the closest thing that I found there

Comment: I don't think this is a good approach, as the MySQL Server and Workbench can be different versions (they are currently on my local machine). Also Workbench being installed does not mean that the server is installed, and vice versa.

Comment: I did realize that the products doesn't seem to have the same version even if they are from the same installer. Any improvement you can think of?

Comment: I forgot to add, I do intend to have workbench, shell, and server installed always. So, it might be a good enough solution for me?

Comment: Do you actually use [shell](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/)? Most users still seem to use the [mysql cli](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html).

Comment: Is that not needed? I actually don't know how to use it and only use workbench. I thought some command line people might like to have it so I thought of including it